# Updating A Column From Another Table And Concatenating Two Columns In Single Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle DB
In SQL:

How to Update one column of a table from a column of another table and how to concatenate two columns of first table in a single query

If column_1 of table_1 matches column_A of table_2, then update column_2 of table_1 from the values of column_B of table_2 and also concatenate column_3 and column_4 of table_1 into column_5 of table_1.

I tried :

```
UPDATE T1
  SET column_2 = T2.column_B,
      column5 = T1.column_3 + T1.column_4
FROM table_1 AS T1
JOIN table_2 AS T2
  ON T2.column_A = T1.column_1
```

I am not getting it

Comment: Whats the "+'' for? Are you concatenating with +, does it work?

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/942011?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: If you are looking to concatenate, you should use the method that works for the database engine you are using.  Oracle has documentation on the topic.

Comment: if you have t1.col3 and t1.col4 why bother concatenating them? seems redundant to me

Answer (score 1):

You are using '+' as string concatenation. Oracle the string concatenation operator is '||' try the below code

```
UPDATE (SELECT t1.column_2 column2, 
               t1.column_3 column3,
               t1.column_4 column4,
               t1.column_5 column5,
               t2.column_B columnb
          FROM table_1 t1,
               table_2 t2
         WHERE t1.column_1 = t2.column_A)
   SET column2 = columnb,
       column5 = column3 || column4
```

Comment: t1.column_2 **column2** Why do you use column2? What does it mean?